# Asserting against Fakes

Tags: unit-testing

If I have a IRepository that Create,Update,Delete and Get an entity from the database and I do a fake for it with a public List inside it.

If I am testing a command that is using it:

1. is a bad practice asserting to the list inside that Fake?
2. If not, how this way of testing is called?
3. Is this an integration or unit test?

I search the entire internet and I can't find a good answer for these questions, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> a bad practice asserting to the list inside that Fake?

Sometimes.

In a test where you are trying to measure that the host process invokes the correct *write side effects* on the repository, then you either have to measure the calls themselves, or you have to measure the effect that those calls have on the data structure.

In a test where the host process should invoke *only read side effects*, then no, you shouldn't be asserting anything about the data structure.

Review

- Sandi Metz: [Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M)
- Katrina Owen: [467 Tests, 0 Failures, 0 Confidence](https://vimeo.com/68730418)

> Is this an integration or unit test?

Beats me; what would you do with the answer to that question if you had it?

I recognize this test as a match for [J. B. Rainsberger's understanding of collaboration test](https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/clearing-up-the-integrated-tests-scam); you are running a simple test to ensure that the command/command-handler consumes the repository contract correctly.

But, assuming that the list backing your repository is not being shared with things outside of the control of the test, then that test is still going to be fast, isolated, reliable, etc, so I would expect it to be part of the suite of tests that you run after each edit to ensure that you haven't broken your production code.

I, myself, tend to ignore the different *labels* we use to classify tests.  The properties of the tests are useful, the constraints required to achieve those properties are useful.  But the labels are only useful for confused communication when talking to someone from another context.